# Firestore, problem retrieving field with custom key

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase firestore to save and retrieve data for my project. For reference, my data structure looks like this:

```
collection
   document
       LO3N83COzWfu:[Array]
       randomisedfield2:[Array]
```

I'm trying to retrieve the randomised fields from the document. When I log document data, everything seems to be fine. When I try to log the field as doc.data().LO3N83COzWfu , it also works. However, I couldn't find an answer as to how I can retrieve the field, when it's requsted using a variable key such as the following:

```
let key = "LO3N83COzWfu";
console.log(doc.data().$[key]);
```

**Error getting document: TypeError: Cannot read property 'LO3N83COzWfu' of undefined**

How can I retrieve the field in such a case? What is the query I need to use?

Comment: remove the `.$` and use just `doc.data()[key]`

Comment: That was much easier than I thought, thank you @dotconnor

Comment: `doc` is a `DocumentSnapshot` and you can retrieve value for a key similarly using `doc.get(key)`